# Does this form of matrix have a name?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm looking for the name of this kind of $n$-by-$n$ matrix:

$$\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
-s_1   & b_{12} & b_{13} & b_{14} \\
b_{21} & -s_2   & b_{23} & b_{24} \\
b_{31} & b_{32} & -s_3   & b_{34} \\
b_{41} & b_{42} & b_{43} & -s_4
\end{array}\right)$$

where $s_i = \sum_{j\neq i} b_{ij}$. This is basically so I can google it, so by name I really mean an appropriate "search string".

Comment: I think it's the Q-matrix of a continuous time Markov chain, but I'm not sure...

Comment: Sounds about right

Comment: It reminds of a adjacency matrix (see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix)). Your matrix is minus the neighborhood matrix for the Besag model ([slide 10](https://www.math.ntnu.no/emner/TMA4300/2016v/slides/INLA_intro_4x1.pdf)).

Answer (score 0):

We have diagonally dominant matrices if absolute values of diagonal elements are larger than sum of absolute values of the others in that row.

Such matrices are invertible, ie. nonzero determinant.

Answer (score 0):

In your matrix the row sums are null.

In a [Stochastic Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix) they are equal to $1$, with the elements being non-negative.

If your $b_{i,j}$'s are also non negative, then your matrix is essentially a diagonal matrix $\times$ (a stochastic matrix minus $I$).
And that in brackets is a matrix that , in a Markov chain, gives the difference between the configuration at step $n+1$ wrt that at step $n$.